vite-node, nodejs-polars and is_between error
I am using node-polarjs to analyse data. I have some scripts that use vite-node wrapper, as the main environment is written for SvelteKit. This gives you magic import options like $env, $lib, etc.
Now, when I am trying to use nodejs-polars in .js file I am getting the following error with vite-node.
import pl from 'nodejs-polars';


/**
 * 
 * @param {pl.DataFrame} df 
 * @param {*} date 
 */
export function getSliceByRegisterdAt(df, startDate, endDate) {
    return df.filter(
        pl.col("registeredAt").is_between(startDate, endDate)
    );
}

The error:
TypeError: __vite_ssr_import_0__.default.col(...).is_between is not a function
    at Module.getSliceByRegisterdAt (/Users/moo/project/src/lib/etl/daily.js:37:32)
    at main (/Users/moo/project/src/scripts/print-daily-joiners-yesterday.js:22:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at /Users/moo/project/src/scripts/print-daily-joiners-yesterday.js:28:1
    at ViteNodeRunner.runModule (file:///Users/moo/project/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:362:5)
    at ViteNodeRunner.directRequest (file:///Users/moo/project/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:346:5)
    at ViteNodeRunner.cachedRequest (file:///Users/moo/project/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:189:14)
    at ViteNodeRunner.executeFile (file:///Users/moo/project/node_modules/vite-node/dist/client.mjs:161:12)
    at CAC.run (file:///Users/moo/project/node_modules/vite-node/dist/cli.mjs:91:5)

Looks like Vite is trying to transform pl (Polars import) input somehow and it fails here.

I am not using nodejs-polars in the browser, only in server-side scripts
How can I tell Vite not to transform this so that I can run this code correctly from a command line script using vite-node
...or am I missing something else here?


Looks like the error message is correct. is_between method is available only in Python Polars. For JavaScript you need to chain:
    return df.filter(
        pl.col("registeredAt").gt(startDate).and(pl.col("registeredAt").lt(endDate))
    );


